# Cannot destructure property 'text' of 'options' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a problem with my discord bot and several commands it has. I have this error when running while it worked fine before.

[image: error of the image]

```js
const {
  SlashCommandBuilder
} = require('@discordjs/builders');

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('remboursementoui')
    .setDescription('demande de remboursement accepter !'),
  async execute(interaction, client) {
    const chan = client.channels.cache.get(interaction.channelId);
    const newname = "Accepter";
    const embed = new client.discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('49ff00')
      .setTitle(' remboursement accepter !')
      .setDescription('Félicitation à toi ta demande de remboursement à été accepter !')
      .setFooter(client.config.footerText, client.user.avatarURL())
      .setTimestamp();
  
      if (chan.name.includes('ticket')) {
        chan.setName("ticket-" + newname)
        interaction.reply({
          ephemeral: false,
          embeds: [embed]
        });
      } else {
        interaction.reply({
          content: 'Vous n\'êtes pas dans un ticket !',
          ephemeral: true
        });
      }; 
  },
    
};
```

I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: There is neither `text` nor `options` variables in the code you've posted

Comment: yes i know , that was i dont understand

Comment: The error states it occures at `MessageEmbed.setFooter`. Can you show the source for `client.config.footerText`

Comment: And what's your discord.js version? v13?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to check the value of `client.config.footerText` According to your error message it's `undefined`.

If you check the [discord.js source code](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/v13/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js#L442-L464) you can see that if the first argument (`options`) is a string, it creates a new object where the `text` is the value of `options`. Later, it tries to destructure it but if the first argument is `undefined`, it can't and will throw a TypeError.

```js
options = { text: options, iconURL: deprecatedIconURL };
// ...
const { text, iconURL } = options;
```

So to fix this, you'll need to set the correct value for `client.config.footerText`. Also, you can see that passing strings for `MessageEmbed#setFooter` is deprecated. You should pass an object with a `text` and an `iconURL`, like this:

```js
.setFooter({
  // make sure client.config.footerText is a string
  text: client.config.footerText, 
  iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL(),
})
```

It's probably also better to use `.displayAvatarURL()` as it returns a default avatar if the user doesn't have any.

Comment: thanks , yes is all litle things who have create issue on my code . 
i work on it and now all is great , thanks !